# Elasticsearch 'between' queries

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I do a 'between' query in Elasticsearch?

Basically, I want this.

Find TermA only if it exists between Phrase1 and Phrase2.

Phrase1 --- TermA --- Phrase2  => Match

A specific example:

Source text :  "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

I want to match, in order.

- PhraseA = "The quick brown"
- Term = "jumped"
- PhraseB = "lazy dog"

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

ES supports regular expressions.

https://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-filter.html#query-dsl-regexp-filter

you should be able to do something like:

```
{
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "regexp":{
                "name.first" : "phraseA.*termA.*phraseB"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the regexp only applies to terms and can't be applied to phrases. I'll edit my original issue.